# Knockoutjs - Autocomplete "steals" change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, autocomplete

I am using an Autocomplete feature, but at the same time I want the change event to save the value in db on blur or change.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="event: {change: $parent.saveVariable},
    autocomplete:{
        url: $root.api.autocomplete.searchMasterVariableUrl(),
        renderitem: renderMasterVariableSearch,
        onselection: function (item) { if (item.text) masterText(item.text); }
    }, 
    autocompletevalue: masterCode" />
```

this doesn't work.... If I remove the autocomplete feature it works!!!!

Any suggestions?

Best Regards
Ano

The implementation of autocomplete is as follows (its a bindinghandler):

(function ($, ko) {

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autocomplete = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var $element = $(element),
            opt = valueAccessor(),
            allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        function writeToModel(newValue) {
            if (!ko.isObservable(allBindings.autocompletevalue) || ko.isWriteableObservable(allBindings.autocompletevalue)) {
                var currentValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.autocompletevalue);

                if (newValue && $.isFunction(opt.valueselector)) {
                    newValue = opt.valueselector.call(this, newValue);
                }
                else if (newValue && newValue.label) {
                    newValue = newValue.label;
                }

                if (currentValue !== newValue) {
                    if (ko.isWriteableObservable(allBindings.autocompletevalue)) {
                        allBindings.autocompletevalue(newValue);
                    }
                    else {
                        allBindings.autocompletevalue = newValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var config = {
            minLength: opt.minLength || 2,
            source: function (request, response) {
                var req = { term: request.term };
                if($.isFunction(opt.requestdataselector)) {
                    opt.requestdataselector.call(this, req);
                }
                $.getJSON(opt.url, req, function (data, status, xhr) {
                    if (opt.label) {
                        if (typeof opt.label === 'string') {
                            $.each(data, function (idx, el) { el.label = el[opt.label]; });
                        }
                        else if ($.isFunction(opt.label)) {
                            $.each(data, function (idx, el) { el.label = opt.label.call(this, el); });
                        }
                    }

                    response(data);
                }).fail(function(error) {
                    toastr.error('Failed autocomplete search: ' + error.responseText);
                });
            },
            focus: function (ev, ui) {
                $element.val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            select: function (ev, ui) {
                $element.val(ui.item.label);

                writeToModel(ui.item);

                if ($.isFunction(opt.onselection)) {
                    var ctx = ko.dataFor(this);
                    opt.onselection.call(ctx, ui.item);

                    if ($.isFunction(opt.afterselection)) {
                        opt.afterselection.call(this, $element, ui.item, this);
                    }
                }

                return false;
            },
            change: function (ev, ui) {
                var val = $(ev.target).val();
                if (opt.allowcustomtext) {
                    writeToModel(val);
                }
                else {
                    if (ko.isObservable(allBindings.autocompletevalue) && allBindings.autocompletevalue() !== val) {
                        $element.val(null);
                        writeToModel(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var subscription;
        if (ko.isWriteableObservable(allBindings.autocompletevalue)) {
            subscription = allBindings.autocompletevalue.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                $element.val(newValue);
            });
            var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.autocompletevalue);
            $element.val(val);
        }

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $element.autocomplete("destroy");
            if (subscription) {
                subscription.dispose();
            }
        });

        $element.autocomplete(config);
        if($.isFunction(opt.onenter)) {
            $element.on('keydown', function (ev) {
                if(ev.keyCode === 13) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    ev.stopPropagation();

                    opt.onenter.call(this, ko.dataFor(ev.target), ev.target);
                }
            });
        }

        if ($.isFunction(opt.renderitem)) {
            $element.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = opt.renderitem;
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var $element = $(element),
            opt = valueAccessor(),
            allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        if (ko.isObservable(allBindings.autocompletevalue)) {
            var val = allBindings.autocompletevalue();
            $element.val(val);
        }
    }
};
```

})(jQuery, ko);

Comment: Could you add the code for the autocomplete implementation?

Comment: have a look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/7bRVH/214/

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code submitted by people above to use autocomplete's change instead.

In short, autocomplete has its own change parameter and callbacks. e.g

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    change: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

[JsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/B53nu/)

```
<label for="name-search">Search language:</label>
<input type="text" id="name-search" data-bind="value: langName, 
ko_autocomplete: { change: handleChange, source: getLangs(), select: addLang }" />
<div style="margin-top:1em">The observable array contains the following elements:
    <ul data-bind="foreach: selectedLangs">
        <li data-bind="text: $data" />
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="pickedval">test</div>
<input type="text" value="for using tab">

ko.bindingHandlers.ko_autocomplete = {
    init: function (element, params) {
        $(element).autocomplete(params());
    },
    update: function (element, params) {
        $(element).autocomplete("option", "source", params().source);
    }
        };
$(document).ready(
function () {

    var availableTags = [{
        label: "ActionScript",
        value: 1
    }, {
        label: "AppleScript",
        value: 2
    }, {
        label: "Asp",
        value: 3
    }, {
        label: "BASIC",
        value: 4
    }, {
        label: "C",
        value: 5
    }, {
        label: "C++",
        value: 6
    }, {
        label: "Clojure",
        value: 7
    }, {
        label: "COBOL",
        value: 8
    }, {
        label: "ColdFusion",
        value: 9
    }, {
        label: "Erlang",
        value: 10
    }, {
        label: "Fortran",
        value: 11
    }, {
        label: "Groovy",
        value: 12
    }, {
        label: "Haskell",
        value: 13
    }, {
        label: "Java",
        value: 14
    }, {
        label: "JavaScript",
        value: 15
    }, {
        label: "Lisp",
        value: 16
    }, {
        label: "Perl",
        value: 17
    }, {
        label: "PHP",
        value: 18
    }, {
        label: "Python",
        value: 19
    }, {
        label: "Ruby",
        value: 20
    }, {
        label: "Scala",
        value: 21
    }, {
        label: "Scheme",
        value: 22
    }];

    // knockout view model                    
    var ViewModel = function () {

        var self = this;

        self.langName = ko.observable();
        self.selectedLangs = ko.observableArray();

        self.handleChange = function () {
            alert("change event fired");
            return true;
        }
        // return some programming languages
        self.getLangs = function () {
            return availableTags;
        }

        // user clicked on a auto complete item
        self.addLang = function (event, ui) {

            $(event.target).val("");
            self.handleChange(event);
            var lang = ui.item.label;
            var id = ui.item.value;

            self.selectedLangs.push("id: " + id + ", Language: " + lang);

            return false;
        }

        return {
            getLangs: self.getLangs,
            addLang: self.addLang,
            langName: self.langName,
            handleChange: self.handleChange,
            selectedLangs: self.selectedLangs
        }
    };

    //bind knockout model
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

});
```

Comment: I can do that? Even if the autocomplete is a binding? I mean data-bind="autocomplete: etc. etc."